# Should HTTP Client parse HTTP Headers in response with the error 404 Not Found

Tags: http, header, client

I cannot find any RFC or Standard of HTTP client behavior in case it gets HTTP response with an error 4xx. I know the 401, 407 are the examples when the HTTP headers are parsed, but...

I have the concrete problem for OPTIONS method (HTTP1.1). The server responses 401 Unauthorized, so client tries to authenticate and re-sends the request with an authentication. After that the response has the error 404 Not Found and HTTP header is filled with Set-Cookie HTTP Header. The client use Apache Java HTTPClient/HTTPComponents, which ignores HTTP headers in case of an error in the response.

Should this HTTP Header be accepted by the client? I believe it should not be, but I cannot find the supportive quotation in the RFC.

Comment: When you say "Should this HTTP Header be accepted" are you referring to Set-Cookie? In which case the HTTP spec is the wrong place to look at; you need to consult RFC 6265.

Comment: Yes in this case I am referring Set-Cookie. It was stated with the hope that there are some general recommendations of this case.

Answer (score 0):

RFC 2616 does not specify that any headers should be ignored, [not for 404 responses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.5) and [not for 4xx responses in general](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4) either.

[RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.2) allows clients to ignore `Set-Cookie` headers, but does not specify situations where that might happen; a single example is given, that does not cover your case:

> the user agent might wish to block responses to "third-party" requests
> from setting cookies

In your case, since your server seems to use HTTP basic access authentication, it does not seem to concern the `Set-Cookie` header. In HTTP basic authentication, the `Authorization` header is sent by the client with *every* request, so there should be no need to keep state in a cookie.

It is not clear from your question if you have a very specific HTTP server that you're talking to, or if you are implementing a general HTTP client that is supposed to work with whatever server you throw it at. If you have such a specific case that the HTTP server you work with sends state with `404` responses, and you're required to honor that state in order to communicate with the server, and you have no control over the server, then it does not matter what the standard says; you *will* honor the state sent, or you will not be able to talk to the server.

If, on the other hand, you're implementing a general client and need it to work regardless of the remote server, then your best bet is to stick to [RFC 1958](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1958#page-5):

> Be strict when sending and tolerant when receiving.
> Implementations must follow specifications precisely when sending to
> the network, and tolerate faulty input from the network. When in
> doubt, discard faulty input silently, without returning an error
> message unless this is required by the specification.

Which, to me, would mean that you should honor the full response received, regardless of the status code, unless you have an objective reason making it impossible for you to do so. I don't see a reason to ignore the state, even if it violates the standard (or in this case, your personal perception of the standard, since it does not say anything about accepting or ignoring the state).

**Update:** [RFC 2617 (HTTP Authentication)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) states:

> A client SHOULD assume that all paths at or deeper than the depth of
> the last symbolic element in the path field of the Request-URI also
> are within the protection space specified by the Basic realm value of
> the current challenge. A client MAY preemptively send the
> corresponding Authorization header with requests for resources in
> that space without receipt of another challenge from the server.

It is highly inconsistent if the server expects HTTP authentication for one URL, but does not honor it for URLs beneath it, requiring a separate cookie-based authentication for them. If anything should be changed in your server implementation, it should be to harmonize the authentication scheme for all resources.

Comment: That's a good answer except the end. The generalisation of the "*Be strict when sending and tolerant when receiving*" principle is one of the worst pieces of advice in software development: you just encourage the remote party to keep sending you non-compliant messages and get away with it. What you then get is a piece of software that doesn't quite follow the specs and never fails, until one day another implementation of that specification follows the specs correctly and fails to interact with the non-compliant implementation (which was simply too tolerant).

Comment: @Bruno Unfortunately, there is very little one can do with faulty remote implementations. There are only two options, really: ignore the faults and do what you can with the parts you _can_ handle; or blacklist the remote altogether and pretend it does not exist. Either option can be the correct approach, depending on the situation. You see my answer as bad, but it is simply pragmatic. You _might_ be in position to enforce strict compliance if others _need_ to talk with you, but there's nothing you can do when _you_ need to talk to others and they're not strict.

Comment: I don't think your answer is bad (just that principle at the end). As you say, the cookie spec allows clients to ignore `Set-Cookie`, which would make the Apache HTTP client lib compliant with RFC 6265 (and 2616) in that respect. Quoting RFC 1958 in here doesn't seem relevant, since RFC 6265 says the recipient of `Set-Cookie` may ignore it anyway. As for being in a position to enforce strict compliance, it's down to market forces unfortunately. Even if you accept the non-compliant message, don't pretend it's valid. The key point here is to *discard* faulty input, not to act upon it.

Comment: Browsers have implemented configuration mechanisms to ignore cookies (both third-party and first-party) for ages. Still, if you set your browser to ignore first-party cookies, _your_ browsing experience will suffer in _almost every case_. If you ignore third-party cookies, the degradation will probably be less-pronounced, but still obvious. It does not really matter if we're talking about a GUI browser or an automated application using a HTTP client library. If _you need_ to access a server to accomplish something, _you_ need to make sure to work with the server's quirks.

Comment: We are trying to be the general WebDAV client. But in this case the client & server are developed by one company, but different teams, so I would like to find out by which team the problem should be fixed.

Comment: How does it matter whether you accept cookies or not when you're authenticating for a non-existent resource, in the context of WebDAV?

Comment: Actually the resource exists. The problem showed up when the access to the root of the WebDAV server was disabled for authenticated users. Since that the server returns 404 Not Found for authenticated users (some security reason). So after authentication handshake the client get Set-Cookie header in the response with the error 404. As it is ignored by the client, the client doesn't send Cookie in the following requests. It means that the client is not authenticated. When it accesses the folders/resources with partial public content and hence the content in incomplete.

Comment: I think the server should behave consistently without the respect to the fact the client is authenticated or not. So it should return 404 immediately instead of 401, not just after authentication.

Comment: This behavior could depend on other concerns. Revealing the existence or non-existence of specific resources within a protected hierarchy could be viewed as a security leak. Think in terms of user/password authentication: replying with separate "user not found" and "incorrect password" errors reveals the existence of specific named user accounts to an unauthenticated attacker, which is why the general consensus is to respond with the same "authentication failed" error in both cases.

Comment: @lanzz Thanks for your valuable input. I appreciate it.